# Best method to use a base website framework that can be referenced by other sites

Tags: php, svn, web-applications, content-management-system

I am currently looking for a more efficient method to develop websites at my place of work. We host over 150 sites, all with varying versions of our main website and CMS framework. A new website tends to be a copy and paste job from what we think is the latest version. Needless to say, this uses a lot of space and is highly inefficient in terms of making updates that we want on all sites, not to mention messy. (Don't blame me, I'm a new employee trying to tidy things up!)

My initial idea is to create a base framework on our server, containing all generic files such as PHP classes, functions, etc. Then each website can simply pull these files, only requiring some include files to do the pulling, a config file for any non-generic variables (such as database credentials) and other non-generic files such as stylesheets, etc.

This then poses the problem that when an update is made to a generic file in the base framework, an error will kill every site that uses that file. My initial thoughts for this were some form of subversion, allowing us to commit and roll-back updates as necessary, adding a little room for error. Then we can make updates to a test area, check it all works then commit the update to the main repository.

Our server is running Linux Red Hat Enterprise 5.3, am I correct in thinking that just using svnserve wont allow us to directly reference the files in the repository? What would be the best method to do this, or is there a better way to go about increasing efficiency and decreasing disk space?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

A scripted deployment system would probably make sense. E.g. create a shell script that can checkout a copy of the repository, then copy it to the destination(s). You can give it a specific revision number as argument, so that you are able to roll back to previous versions.

There are entire frameworks built around just getting this part right, but if you can get started with some home-baked scripts, you'll probably be better suited to understand those.

If you don't have specific experience with subversion, I would suggest that you try to base your self on git rather. It's much better on a lot of points, not the least on being faster and it is quickly becoming the de facto tool.

Comment: That will still mean that the website code will be replicated for each site, ideally I want to have the generic files in one location where they can just be included in PHP. With regards to GIT, that is something I've looked at but not yet in great detail. Is there any chance you could briefly explain how it could be used in this scenario, it would be a great help.

Comment: The duplication isn't an issue if just it's automated. E.g. you have a folder under each site, that you never manually access, but which your deployment tool manages for you.